# React-Router Best way to translate routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a react app which needs to be available in 3 languages.
Right now, it has only the english version - I'm using react router for managing     the pages.

**I dont need to translte it, I already have the translations,  but I dont know how to implement these in my app.**
Duplicating 3 times my project to /en , /it , /fr sounds inefficient.

Any suggestions?

```
     <Router >

 <div>
 <Switch>

  <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}  />
  <Route exact path="/where" component={Where}  />
  <Route exact path="/about" component={About}  />
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}  />
  <Route component={NotFound}  />

  </Switch>

  </div>

  </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Router params for language

```
<Router >
  <Route path="/:language" component={Localise}/>
</Router>
```

and In localise component

```
render() {
    const {language} = this.props.match.params; 
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path=`${match.path}/contact` component={Contact}  />
              <Route exact path=`${match.path}/where` component={Where}  />
              <Route exact path=`${match.path}/about` component={About}  />
              <Route exact path={match.path} component={Home}  />
              <Route component={NotFound}  />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and is it a good aproach to use an “case” statement to print the content according to the /:lang param? Or theres a better way?

Comment: You would be using using some library to translate the content right? So in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate lifecycle method you can fetch the paramerized data and use it according to the language selected

Comment: No . I already have the translated content, no additional libraries.